# Swiftで構造体をNSMutableArrayの要素として挿入したいのですが、 オブジェクト型に変換する必要があるのでしょうか？

Tags: swift

Swiftで構造体をNSMutableArrayの要素として挿入したいのですが、
オブジェクト型に変換する必要があるのでしょうか？

CGRectなどをNSNumberにして挿入するのと同様に
できるのでしょうか？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

「オブジェクト型」がなんのことなのか、ちょっと理解できない面がありますが、`CGRect`が、そのままでは`NSMutableArray`の要素にならないことは、Swiftでも同様です。
`CGRect`（C言語の構造体）を、インスタンス（Objective-C）にラップ（Wrap）するには、（`NSNumber`でなくて）`NSValue`クラスを使います。

```
import UIKit

// CGRectのオブジェクトを作成
let rect1 = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 30.0, height: 30.0)
let rect2 = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 30.0, width: 30.0, height: 30.0)
let rect3 = CGRect(x: 30.0, y: 0.0, width: 30.0, height: 30.0)
let rect4 = CGRect(x: 30.0, y: 30.0, width: 30.0, height: 30.0)

// CGRectのオブジェクトを、Objective-Cのインスタンスにラッピング
let objcRect1 = NSValue(CGRect: rect1)
let objcRect2 = NSValue(CGRect: rect2)
let objcRect3 = NSValue(CGRect: rect3)
let objcRect4 = NSValue(CGRect: rect4)

// Objective-CのインスタンスをSwiftの配列に格納
var newArray: [AnyObject] = [objcRect1, objcRect2, objcRect3, objcRect4]
// Swiftの配列をNSArrayにキャスト（NSMutableArrayではない）
var objcArray: NSArray = newArray as NSArray

// 配列から2番目の要素を取りだす。
let newObjcRect: NSValue = objcArray[1] as! NSValue
// NSValueインスタンスから、CGRectをアンラップ（Unwrap）
let newRect: CGRect = newObjcRect.CGRectValue()
```

Objective-Cのクラスとブリッジすることがなければ、どう考えても`NS(Mutable)Array`を使うメリットはないですね。

---

`CGRect`のような既存の構造体ではなくて、新規にSwiftの構造体を作るのなら、構造体（`struct`）ではなくて、クラス（`class`）として定義すれば、`NS(Mutable)Array`のメンバーに直接することができます。

```
import UIKit

// MySizeというクラスを定義
class MySize {
    var width: Float = 0.0
    var height: Float = 0.0
    
    init(width: Float, height: Float) {
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
    }
}

let size1 = MySize(width: 30.0, height: 30.0)
let size2 = MySize(width: 40.0, height: 40.0)
let size3 = MySize(width: 50.0, height: 50.0)
let size4 = MySize(width: 60.0, height: 60.0)

// クラスなら、NSMutableArrayのメンバーになる。
var objcSizes = NSMutableArray(capacity: 4)
objcSizes.addObject(size1)
objcSizes.addObject(size2)
objcSizes.addObject(size3)
objcSizes.addObject(size4)

// 配列から取り出しも、このとおり。
if let theSize = objcSizes[1] as? MySize {
    let theWidth = theSize.width
}
```

同様のことを、構造体でやろうとすると、「Argument type 'MySize' does not conform to expected type ‘AnyObject'」というコンパイルエラーが出ます。